# Is there any reason for numeric rather than int in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, t-sql, types

Why would someone use numeric(12, 0) datatype for a simple integer ID column? If you have a reason why this is better than int or bigint I would like to hear it.

We are not doing any math on this column, it is simply an ID used for foreign key linking.

I am compiling a list of programming errors and performance issues about a product, and I want to be sure they didn't do this for some logical reason. If you follow this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

... you can see that the numeric(12, 0) uses 9 bytes of storage and being limited to 12 digits, theres a total of 2 trillion numbers if you include negatives. WHY would a person use this when they could use a bigint and get 10 million times as many numbers with one byte less storage. Furthermore, since this is being used as a product ID, the 4 billion numbers of a standard int would have been more than enough.

So before I grab the torches and pitch forks - tell me what they are going to say in their defense?

And no, I'm not making a huge deal out of nothing, there are hundreds of issues like this in the software, and it's all causing a huge performance problem and using too much space in the database. And we paid over a million bucks for this crap... so I take it kinda seriously.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Perhaps they're used to working with Oracle?

All numeric types including ints are normalized to a standard single representation among all platforms.

Comment: Boom goes the dynamite :)

Apparently the old version of this database was Oracle.

Answer (score 8):

There are many reasons to use numeric - for example - financial data and other stuffs which need to be accurate to certain decimal places. However for  the example you cited above, a simple int would have done.

Perhaps sloppy programmers working who didn't know how to to design a database ?

Answer (score 4):

Before you take things too seriously, what is the data storage requirement for each row or set of rows for this item?

Your observation is correct, but you probably don't want to present it too strongly if you're reducing storage from 5000 bytes to 4090 bytes, for example.

You don't want to blow your credibility by bringing this up and having them point out that any measurable savings are negligible.  ("Of course, many of our lesser-experienced staff also make the same mistake.")

Can you fill in these blanks?

```
with the data type change, we use
    ____ bytes of disk space instead of ____
    ____ ms per query instead of ____
    ____ network bandwidth instead of ____
    ____ network latency instead of ____
```

That's the kind of thing which will give you credibility.

Comment: Since this ID code is copied across many tables, used in queries by the API, and used for joins, it's not simply a matter of saving one byte per row - it's a matter of saving data in indexes, optimizing joins, reducing network overhead, etc...

Comment: Exactly.  Quantify that and you will have a strong case for your decision.  the objections I made were just examples of objections you might hear, and should be ready to answer.

Answer (score 3):

How old is this application that you are looking into?

Previous to SQL Server 2000 there was no bigint. Maybe its just something that has made it from release to release for many years without being changed or the database schema was copied from an application that was this old?!?

Comment: It is new since SQL 2000. However, it's possible the database is based on some older design - but that would mean they sold us something that isn't what they said it was.

Answer (score 1):

In your example I can't think of any logical reason why you wouldn't use INT. I know there are probably reasons for other uses of numeric, but not in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

According to: http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/da-db_1.htm

> **decimal**
>
> Fixed precision and scale numeric data from -10^38 -1 through 10^38 -1.
>
> **numeric**
>
> A synonym for decimal.
>
> **int**
>
> Integer (whole number) data from -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) through 2^31 - 1 (2,147,483,647).

It is impossible to know if there is a reason for them using decimal, since we have no code to look at though.

Comment: Odd that that refer to ints as "whole numbers" when they're allowed to be negative.

Comment: Negative numbers are whole numbers - they don't have a fractional part. They are not "counting numbers" by most definitions, but they are whole.

Comment: The term whole number is used by various authors to mean a natural number, which is either:
the nonnegative integers (0, 1, 2, 3, ...)
the positive integers (1, 2, 3, ...)

Answer (score 0):

In some databases, using a decimal(10,0) creates a packed field which takes up less space.  I know there are many tables around my work that use that.  They probably had the same kind of thought here, but you have gone to the documentation and proven that to be incorrect.  More than likely, I would say it will boil down to a case of "that's the way we have always done it, because someone one time said it was better".

Answer (score 0):

It is possible they spend a LOT of time in MS Access and see 'Number' often and just figured, its a number, why not use numeric?

Based on your findings, it doesn't sound like they are the optimization experts, and just didn't know. I'm wondering if they used schema generation tools and just relied on them too much.

I wonder how efficient an index on a decimal value (even if 0 scale is set) for a primary key compares to a pure integer value.

Like Mark H. said, other than the indexing factor, this particular scenario likely isn't growing the database THAT much, but if you're looking for ammo, I think you did find some to belittle them with.

Comment: I have plenty of mistakes to point out - the kind that I'm sure of. This one just came as such a surprise it one of those "there must be a reason for this" kind of things. I.E. it is so weird that it must be on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In your citation, the decimal shows precision of 1-9 as using 5 bytes. Your column apparently has 12,0 - using 4 bytes of storage - same as integer.

Moreover, INT, datatype can go to a power of 31:
-2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647)

While decimal is much larger to 38:
 - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1

So the software creator was actually providing more while using the same amount of storage space.

Now, with the basics out of the way, the software creator actually limited themselves to just 12 numbers or 123,456,789,012 (just an example for place holders not a maximum number). If they used INT they could not scale this column - it would go up to the full 31 digits. Perhaps there is a business reason to limit this column and associated columns to 12 digits.

An INT is an INT, while a DECIMAL is scalar.

Hope this helps.

PS: 
The whole number argument is:
A) Whole numbers are 0..infinity
B) Counting (Natural) numbers are 1..infinity
C) Integers are infinity (negative) .. infinity (positive)
D) I would not cite WikiANYTHING for anything. Come on, use a real source! May as well be http://MyPersonalMathCite.com

Comment: ? According to Microsoft documentation on t-sql (the link provided by the original poster), 12,0 precision takes 9 bytes, not 4.